# Cascading wrapper components in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

Given the following "wrapper component" `DefaultButton` for a Quasar `QBtn`, I make use of `v-bind="$attrs"` and a `v-for` loop for passing down the slots.

**DefaultButton.vue**

```
<template>
  <q-btn v-bind="$attrs" color="primary" outline rounded>
    <template v-for="(_, slot) in $slots" #[slot]="scope">
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope || {}" />
    </template>
  </q-btn>
</template>

<script setup></script>
```

Now if I'd like to create another wrapper for `DefaultButton.vue`, is it necessary to repeat inserting `v-bind="$attrs"` and the slot template?

**SomeIconButton.vue**

```
<template>
  // Is this sufficient?
  <default-btn icon="some-icon"></default-btn>

  // Or is this required?
  <default-btn v-bind="$attrs" icon="some-icon">
    <template v-for="(_, slot) in $slots" #[slot]="scope">
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope || {}" />
    </template>
  </default-btn>
</template>

<script setup />
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, you would need to repeat the `v-bind="$attrs"` and the slot template at each nesting level.

Comment: @tony19 Why is it so for $attrs? A child receives them unless it has inheritAttrs: false, or they need to be passed to another element rather than root. This seems to be not the case for these comps.

Comment: Just found this documentation on fallthrough attributes: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html

Comment: @EstusFlask IMO it's better to explicitly bind `$attrs` on the target node in case the element template is later modified such that the target node is no longer the root node (which has often happened in my experience). If that's unlikely in the OP's project, then I agree there's no need to re-bind `$attrs`.